# Unable to Start GParted

Tags: filesystems, usb-drive, gparted

I've been doing some work with various USB drives and have been using Gparted to do so. However, for no apparent reason, `gparted` no longer starts.

If I open the graphical application, I authenticate with my password and then nothing happens.

If I run `sudo gparted`. I get:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /run/udisks2/inhibit-polkit, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail  or so

When I run `dmesg` I get:

```
[ 1225.545050] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[ 1225.568016] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583
[ 1225.568027] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1225.568033] usb 2-1: Product: Ultra Fit
[ 1225.568038] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 1225.568042] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 4C531001390502102383
[ 1225.570640] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1225.572092] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 1226.571712] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra Fit        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1226.572353] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 1226.574166] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 242614272 512-byte logical blocks: (124 GB/115 GiB)
[ 1226.577102] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1226.577115] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 1226.578691] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1226.596148]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1226.600044] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1226.886103] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 1237.359985] sdb: detected capacity change from 124218507264 to 0
[ 1251.998948] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 23
```

I left out the top part because it doesn't contain much, or so I think. What I find curious is that the SanDisk Ultrafit listed here is not actually inserted into any usb drive and hasn't been for a few hours. This was one of the drives I was formatting.

Why is it still showing up here and does this have something to do with this? Should I somehow explicitly unmount it? I've read where Gparted does this in some instances where some part of the file system of a drive is not understood.

How should I proceed to be able to run `gparted` again?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `gksudo`.

Comment: Using gksudo offers the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot, **carefully** run `gparted` on a disk known to be working, for example `gparted /dev/sda` -- just to see if the GUI starts correctly.  If that works, close `gparted` without changing anything.

If the problem is the `gparted` software, reboot from your favorite Linux bootCD, (or live USB), one that does have a working `gparted`, and test any questionable drives from there.

But if `gparted` started correctly on `/dev/sda`, then the fault is in the USB drive(s).  Then, maybe:

1. the USB drive's partition table is corrupt. If the data is important, back it up with `gddrescue`, then see if [`gpart`](https://github.com/baruch/gpart) can guess where the partitions should be, and proceed accordingly.
2. the table is in [some newer format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table) that `gparted` doesn't know about,
3. there might be no partition table at all, the whole disk might be one file system. In which case try mounting it.  The `dmesg` output seems to suggest that it *is* mounted.

Comment: Thanks for your post! I just tried to run gparted on a usb drive that I know works using gparted /dev/sdX but get the same error message. I am concerned because even if no USB drives are inserted I can't start the gparted GUI in any way. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are using VMWorkstation:

I once used GParted to enlarge my /dev/sda1 (Ubuntu 14.04 64). Here is what I have done:

1. Download [GParted ISO source (SourceForge)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.21.0-1/gparted-live-0.21.0-1-amd64.iso/download?use_mirror=jaist&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnblogs.com%2F&use_mirror=jaist).
2. Go to **Settings**, find **CD/DVD(SATA)**, click on **using ISO file**, and add the ISO which you just downloaded.
3. Start the system and **KEEP PRESSING** <kbd>F2</kbd> (check it, maybe different, this one is difficult, you have to do this fast), or click on the green arrow, choose the **POWER ON TO BIOS** (recommended).
4. Choose **BOOT**, and move the **CD-ROM drive** to the first one, press <kbd>F10</kbd> save and exit.
5. Now wait for a second and you are in **GParted live**. (Be careful changing memory.)

Answer (score 0):

@chronic788 I had the same pb. in my case after upgrading `gparted` from a Launchpad PPA repository.

Although my /dev/sdc disk is fine, `gparted` complains :

```bash
$ sudo -b gparted /dev/sdc
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /run/udisks2/inhibit-polkit,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

My analysis :

`gparted` is a bash script that does a few checks before calling `gpartedbin`, so I can search for `udisks2.inhibit` inside the `gparted` script :

```bash
$ grep /usr/.*/udisks2.inhibit $(which gparted)
if test -x "/usr/lib/udisks2/udisks2-inhibit"; then
    /usr/lib/udisks2/udisks2-inhibit $BASE_CMD
$ grep "\bmount" $(locate /udisks2-inhibit | head -1) | tail -1
mount --move /run/udisks2/inhibit-polkit "$DIR"
```

The `mount --move /run/udisks2/inhibit-polkit $DIR` command was the one responsible here for the above error.

My workaround is to temporally disable (only for 1 second) `udisks2-inhibit` and then re-enable it right after `gparted` is launched in the background (`sudo -b`), hence the `sleep 1` command :

```bash
$ sudo chmod -v -x /usr/lib/udisks2/udisks2-inhibit;sudo -b gparted /dev/sdc;sleep 1;sudo chmod -v +x /usr/lib/udisks2/udisks2-inhibit
mode of ‘/usr/lib/udisks2/udisks2-inhibit’ changed from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================
Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag
mode of ‘/usr/lib/udisks2/udisks2-inhibit’ changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
```